# Website Version PHP

Tags: php, mysqli, version

I am trying to create a version file that will alert the end user if there is an update.

In theory and practical application:

When the admin logs in and goes to their Management interface, a script reads a remote file and compares the remote version with the local version, if they are the same, report that status, if remote is greater, alert.

The local version is pulled from a MySQL table with MySQLi and confirmed to work, the remote file is read, confirmed to work as well how ever I am running into an issue.

Local version is 1.3, remote version is 1.3 yet it reports:

```
    Your Version - 1.3 is OUT OF DATE, new version 1.3 is available for download
```

When it should say

```
    Your Version is UP TO DATE!
```

The code I am using is below

```
    require_once('includes/settings.php');

    function check_version() {
    global $connection;
   $query = "SELECT * from version";
   $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

   // if the query fails, die and report
  if(!$result = $connection->query($query)){
    die('There was an error running the query [' . $connection->error .     ']');
   }
   else {
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    $my_version = $row['minor'];
    echo '<p>Local = '.$my_version.'</p>';

    $ctx = stream_context_create(array(
            'http' => array(
                'timeout' => 1
            )
     ));        

    $rversion = file_get_contents("http://www.twedev.com/projects/microcms/version", 0, $ctx);

    echo $rversion;
    var_dump($rversion);


    if ($my_version === $rversion) {
       $dev_msg = '<strong>Your Micro CMS Version - '.$my_version.' is CURRENT</strong>';
    }

    elseif ($my_version != $rversion) {
       $dev_msg = '<strong>Your Micro CMS Version - '.$my_version.' is OUT OF DATE,<br> new version '.$rversion.' is available for download</strong>';
    }
    else {
       $dev_msg = '<strong>Something went wrong with the version server</strong>';
    }
}
return $dev_msg;
}

?>
```

What I need is another set of eyes to look through this is point me in the right direction if possible, this has me overly frustrated today.

Comment: Try adding `var_dump($my_version, $rversion);`. That will make it easy to see what's different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the `===` [identical operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) to compare values, using that instead of `==` will compare the value and the type of value.

The value you are getting from file_get_contents() it's a string, and the version number seems to be something different to string, probably a float number.

**Update**: After using var_dump on both vars we could see the result wasn't the same, and the solution was to use [`trim`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) to strip whitespaces from the end of the string.

Comment: I have tried using =, == and many others, the remote version reports whats in the remote version file, same result every time

Comment: What is the whole result from execution? Specially if you do before a comparation a `var_dump` from `$my_version` an `$rversion`

Comment: 1.3 on both, I have tried that to compare and it's giving the desired result but over all, it gives me the wrong reporting

Comment: string(4) "1.3 " string(3) "1.3"

Comment: Please use `var_dump` and show the results of both vars, `var_dump` doesn't show the value as a echo, it show also the type.

Comment: As you can see in the result, the first has 4 chars and the second just three. You must use [`trim`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) on your value to remove trailing spaces.

Comment: trim worked, don't know why I hadnt thought of that, thanks Miguel